# Rubygems 1.3.7 setup error

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am setting up a server and decided to install the latest Ruby from source. I downloaded ruby-1.9.2-p0.tar.gz and installed that with no problems. 
Next up, was installing Rubygems. Using the 1.3.7 I downloaded from Rubyforge I ran setup.rb and got the error:

```
./setup.rb: 13: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "then")
```

This is all happening in a clean install of Ubuntu server 10.10.
Line 13, for the curious, is this:

```
  config = defined?(RbConfig) ? RbConfig : Config
```

Any thoughts on what this could be? Has someone else run into this?

Comment: can you try installing rvm and ruby 1.8.7p302 to see if it's ruby related problem? Also, have you tried modifying that line to try and fix the syntax error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I just needed to add:

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```